# Some doubts about Destination NAT

Tags: networking, router, nat

I am kind of a noob when it comes to computer networking.
I have been studying NAT for a while, but I am having a hard time trying to figure out what exactly **Destination NAT** does in some circumstances. In particular, can **dst-nat** be also used to change packets'IP headers coming from your own LAN ports other than only from WAN port(for port-forwarding i.e.)?

Comment: Why would you have NAT inside your local network?

Comment: @harrymc. I saw it be used for DNS redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DNAT and/or SNAT can be used between *any two interfaces*. There's technically no difference between 'LAN' and 'WAN' in this situation. As long as all packets (requests *and* responses) go through two different interfaces on the router, then NAT **can** be used.

Note that the "two interfaces" rule has to apply to both the original packet *and* the rewritten packet. So if you want to redirect a LAN→WAN connection back to the same LAN, please search this site for "hairpin" first.

Whether NAT **should** be used between LAN subnets is a different question. There are some legitimate uses for DNAT – such as redirecting old address to new server – however, the same cannot be said about SNAT. The only place you should ever use SNAT is on the WAN interface.

---

However, if by "LAN ports" you mean a *single* subnet, then no – packets with the same subnet as source and destination do not actually go *through* a router and **cannot** be NATed.

Most home routers have all LAN ports on a single subnet, so they bypass NAT rules. (In fact the 4 'LAN' ports are usually switched at hardware level and bypass the router's CPU entirely.)

There is one exception: Using "client isolation" (aka PVLAN) together with "proxy ARP" will force even same-subnet packets to go through the router and makes NAT possible again.

Comment: Yes, I got what SNAT is for and which is the only place one should ever use it (masquerading for example). I was trying to make sense of DNAT completely too. I saw it be used to redirect DNS requests coming from  LAN. As I said, I thought that it could be set only on Ip packets coming from WAN, say internet, but it seems that I was wrong. "Incoming packets" are also those coming from a LAN. Correct? Thanks

Comment: Yes. All packets which arrive at the device are "incoming", even if they come from LAN interface.

Comment: For the record, I have been learning how a Mikrotik router works.

Comment: Yes, That was exactly what I am trying to figure out. DNS redirect makes much sense to me now. Thanks